# Alguna alternativa al ifelse?

Tags: r, if, data

Estoy ante un problema que no sé muy bien cómo resolver. Tengo 2 dataframes (muy grandes) de  dimensiones DIFERENTES que contienen información de estaciones meteorológicas de manera diaria durante 15 años. El problema que tengo es que la misma estación tiene nombre diferente en cada df y debo unificar todo en un solo df. Intentaré explicarme con un ejemplo pequeñito:

```
df1 # Este df tiene "escritas" todas las fechas posibles (2000-01-01 al 2015-31-12), pero realmente sólo registró Temp y humedad del 2000-01-01 al 2008-31-12

ID       Lat      Lon         Alt     Fecha          Temp    Humedad
C065    43.2112   -3.40713    677     2000-01-01     25       50
C065    43.2112   -3.40713    677     2000-02-01     12       55
C065    43.2112   -3.40713    677     2000-03-01     18       58 
C065    43.2112   -3.40713    677     2015-01-01     9999     9999 #Esto significa que no tiene registro
C054    43.0423   -2.65763    556     2000-01-01     12       35
C054    43.0423   -2.65763    556     2000-02-01     9        35
C054    43.0423   -2.65763    556     2000-03-01     10       38
C054    43.0423   -2.65763    556     2015-01-01     9999     9999
C035    42.9661   -2.86795    618     2000-12-13     2        25
C035    42.9661   -2.86795    618     2000-12-14     4        22
C035    42.9661   -2.86795    618     2000-12-14     8        27

df2 # Este df tiene "escritas" todas las fechas posibles (2000-01-01 al 2015-31-12), pero realmente sólo registró Temp y humedad del 2009-01-01 al 2015-31-12  

ID       Lat      Lon         Alt     Fecha          Temp    Humedad
GH65    43.2112   -3.40713    677     2000-01-01     9999    9999
GH65    43.2112   -3.40713    677     2009-01-01     35       60
GH65    43.2112   -3.40713    677     2009-02-01     32       55
GH65    43.2112   -3.40713    677     2015-01-01     28       58 
GH54    43.0423   -2.65763    556     2015-01-12     22       62
GH54    43.0423   -2.65763    556     2015-02-12     28       65
GH54    43.0423   -2.65763    556     2015-03-12     30       68
```

Como se observa, C065 y GH65 son la misma estación, pues están en las mismas coordenadas. Ahora bien, lo que debo hacer es unificar con un único nombre aquellas estaciones que coincidan en coordenadas, bien sea llamándolas C065 o GH 65. También debería poder hacer que se complementen, es decir, que de C065 sólo tome los registros reales (2000 al 2008) y del GH65 también (2009-2015) 
Se me había ocurrido hacerlo usando ifelse

```
df1$ID2 <- ifelse(df1$Lat == df2$Lat & df1$Lon == df2$Lon & df1$Alt == df2$Alt, df1$ID ,"NO")
```

pero como los dos df no tienen el mismo número de registros, no funcionará.
Alguna sugerencia para resolverlo? Tendré que hacer un bucle?

Espero haberme echo entender, sé que es medio complicado de explicar los datos que tengo y lo que quiero hacer.

Gracias de antemano por cualquier idea.

Caro

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, reproducimos tu ejemplo:

```
df1 <- read.table(text= "ID       Lat      Lon         Alt     Fecha          Temp    Humedad
C065    43.2112   -3.40713    677     2000-01-01     25       50
C065    43.2112   -3.40713    677     2000-02-01     12       55
C065    43.2112   -3.40713    677     2000-03-01     18       58 
C065    43.2112   -3.40713    677     2015-01-01     9999     9999
C054    43.0423   -2.65763    556     2000-01-01     12       35
C054    43.0423   -2.65763    556     2000-02-01     9        35
C054    43.0423   -2.65763    556     2000-03-01     10       38
C054    43.0423   -2.65763    556     2015-01-01     9999     9999
C035    42.9661   -2.86795    618     2000-12-13     2        25
C035    42.9661   -2.86795    618     2000-12-14     4        22
C035    42.9661   -2.86795    618     2000-12-14     8        27", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- read.table(text= "ID       Lat      Lon         Alt     Fecha          Temp    Humedad
GH65    43.2112   -3.40713    677     2000-01-01     9999    9999
GH65    43.2112   -3.40713    677     2009-01-01     35       60
GH65    43.2112   -3.40713    677     2009-02-01     32       55
GH65    43.2112   -3.40713    677     2015-01-01     28       58 
GH54    43.0423   -2.65763    556     2015-01-12     22       62
GH54    43.0423   -2.65763    556     2015-02-12     28       65
GH54    43.0423   -2.65763    556     2015-03-12     30       68", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Luego, usando `tidyverse` la idea es:

- Combinar los dos `data.frame` en uno solo
- Construir el nuevo ID, para esto creamos un nuevo `df` con `Lat` , `Lon` y `Alt`, el nuevo ID será el primero que aparezca de cada grupo
- Por último agregamos el nuevo ID a los datos

Solución:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# unimos ambos df en uno nuevo
# y de paso convertimos Fecha a Date
df1 %>%
    union(df2) %>%
    mutate(Fecha = as.Date(Fecha)) %>%
    as.tibble() -> newdf

# Creamos un nuevo df para generar los grupos
# Generamos un nuevo id con el primer valor de cada grupo
newdf %>%
    group_by(Lat, Lon, Alt) %>%
    summarise(newid=first(ID)) -> grupos

# Genermos el df final con el nuevo id
newdf %>%
    left_join(grupos, by=c("Lat", "Lon", "Alt")) %>%
    select(newid, everything()) %>%
    arrange(newid) -> newdf
```

El nuevo `data.frame` tendrá una columna nueva `newid` que representa el `ID` unificado, por ejemplo:

```
newdf %>%
    filter(newid=='GH65')

# A tibble: 8 x 8
  newid ID      Lat   Lon   Alt Fecha       Temp Humedad
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr>      <int>   <int>
1 GH65  GH65   43.2 -3.41   677 2015-01-01    28      58
2 GH65  GH65   43.2 -3.41   677 2009-02-01    32      55
3 GH65  GH65   43.2 -3.41   677 2009-01-01    35      60
4 GH65  GH65   43.2 -3.41   677 2000-01-01  9999    9999
5 GH65  C065   43.2 -3.41   677 2015-01-01  9999    9999
6 GH65  C065   43.2 -3.41   677 2000-03-01    18      58
7 GH65  C065   43.2 -3.41   677 2000-02-01    12      55
8 GH65  C065   43.2 -3.41   677 2000-01-01    25      50
```

El filtrar luego por fecha es trivial usando la funcionalidad de `tidyverse/dplyr` y gracias a que antes hemos convertido `Fecha` a un `Date`:

```
newdf %>%
    filter(year(Fecha) >= 2009 & year(Fecha) <= 2015 & ID == 'GH65')
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando el paquete sqldf se puede resolver con la cómoda sintaxis de SQL para hacer JOIN.

```
library("sqldf")
dfout <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM df1 JOIN df2 ON df1.Lat=df2.Lat AND df1.Lon=df2.Lon AND df1.Alt=df2.Alt")
```

El problema es que tienes varias entradas en la misma fecha de la misma estación, por lo que no va a hacer bien el JOIN.